# AJAX TabPanels - How to remove panel Outline/Border

Tags: ajax

I've tried specifying a few different border properties but I can't seem to do anything to get rid of that outline around each tab panel.  Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Comment: are you using a specific library/plugin? we need more detail

Comment: When you say pabel, do you mean panel or label?

Comment: No specific library or plugin. Just a simple AJAX Tab Container and Panels as specified here:http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to override these styles.

[Override me http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/2209/screenshot20091216at104.png](http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/2209/screenshot20091216at104.png)